# Can I use past continuous here?

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

> A:..Then I sent you a message from the cafe to to say where I was
>      last night.
>
> B:  I didn't get any texts from you yesterday! I **tried** to phone
>      you but there was no answer.

I have two questions:

1)Can I use here *past continuous* **to emphasise continuous action**(several attempts to get through)? *(because, as I feel, past simple doesn't emphasise the process itself)*:

> I **was trying** to phone you but there was no answer.

2)What is the meaning of past simple in this context:

- Person B was struggling to get through and it was continuous action

**OR**

- Tried only the once and it was a single action?

Answer (score 1):

Neither form of the verb (**tried** or **was trying**) makes it clear whether one or more attempts was involved.

Although both forms are idiomatic, it is more likely that someone would say something like:

> I have been trying to phone you
>   or, specifically
>   I (have) tried to phone you several times

The past continuous form is more often used to say what someone was doing when something else occurred, as in:

> I was trying to phone you when my battery went flat
>   or
>   I was trying to phone you when I dropped my phone and broke it.

However, the choice of tense and construction really depends on personal preference - and another view is offered in FumbleFingers' comment below).

Comment: I can't agree that the ***tried / trying*** choice has no implications for ***number of attempts made***.  In practice a native speaker wouldn't be likely to deliberately choose the continuous to make that distinction with OP's *exact* example, but surely the difference is quite clear if we compare ***Did you try** to ring me yesterday?* and ***Were you trying** to ring me yesterday?* I'm in no doubt the latter strongly implies *My phone rang **several times** [but I didn't answer it]*, but not the former.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't argue with your illustrations. But I didn't say it had no implications. I said it wasn't clear. However, you comment will show OP the other half of the coin.

Comment: I think the basic issue here is that OP needs to be made aware that *I was trying to call you yesterday* simply isn't something a native speaker would ever say in the context he's thinking of (with no ***when-*** clause or similar), so it's ***irrelevant*** to the exact context whether you could use this as a way of implying "multiple attempts". Effectively, the only way to convey that is to explicitly say something like *I tried to call **several times*** - but the distinction he's reaching for *does* exist with the examples in my comment.